# TeX4ht Some Turkish Characters Appear as Images

Tags: tex4ht

When using `htlatex` command, the turkish characters "ç" "ğ" "ş" "ü" appear OK but when it comes to "ı", TeX4ht produces an image. Is there any way around this?

Edit: When I use another font like `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}`, the letter "ı" never appears.

```
\documentclass[18pt]{article}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\Huge ÖÇŞİĞÜöçşığü}
\end{center}
ÖÇŞİĞÜöçşığü


\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Edit 2:

I have tried adding

```
\ifdefined\HCode\else
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\fi

\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

at the beginning and run

```
htlatex index.tex "xhtml,charset=utf-8" "-cunihtf -utf8"
```

the output is as follows.

[image]

Comment: the space before ` -cunihtf` is important, it doesń't work without it. alternatively, you can use [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht), which is frontend for `tex4ht` and it has `-u` option for unicode output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use special command line options to output the file in `utf-8` encoding:

```
htlatex filename "xhtml,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

regarding `mathdesign` package, many fonts are currently not supported by `tex4ht` usual way to solve package conflicts is to use conditional package loading:

```
\documentclass[18pt]{article}

\ifdefined\HCode\else
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\fi

\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\Huge ÖÇŞİĞÜöçşığü}
\end{center}
ÖÇŞİĞÜöçşığü


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this without `mathdesign`. The result is even worse. Should I force the browser to use UTF-8 some way?